# Best way to distribute modules used the same framework

Tags: node.js, npm, rollupjs

I am creating my first open source project, and I am making some plugins for it.  These plugins will be published as npm packages, and they will have identical dependencies.

My question is, what I the best way to deliver them and avoid code repetition?  I know I can use something like Rollup.js to pack all dependencies used by that module in the final distribution js file, but if the user is using multiple modules, the inlined dependencies will be repeated and make the file bloat.

I know end user can use a bundler to remove those repeated codes, but is there anything more I can do to reduce the size of my distribution js files?

Comment: "but if the user is using multiple modules, the inlined dependencies will be repeated" I don't think so...

Comment: Why not?  If I am using the same library for these modules.

Comment: Because packers don't include the same module several times.

Comment: That's it exactly what I tried to say initially.  If the end user use packer then the repeated code will be gone, but what if they don't?  So I was asking the best practice for this, as this is my first time publishing my own modules.